# How to make bash script take file names with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, ifs

I have a bash script like this:

```
myfiles=("file\ with\ spaces.csv")

for file_name in "${myfiles[@]}"
do
        echo "removing first line of file $file_name"
        echo "first line is `head -1 $file_name`"
        echo "\n"
done
```

but it does not recognize the spaces for some reason, even though I enclosed it in double quotes `""`:

```
head: cannot open ‘file\\’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need double quotes inside the backticks. The outer set isn't sufficient.

```
echo "first line is `head -1 "$file_name"`"
```

Also, do not put backslashes in the file name, since it's already quoted. Quotes or backslashes, but not both.

```
myfiles=("file with spaces.csv")
myfiles=(file\ with\ spaces.csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@JohnKugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856437/96588):

- [Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) takes a bit of getting used to in Bash. As a simple rule use single quotes for static strings with no special characters, double quotes for strings with variables, and `$''` quoting for strings with special characters.
- There's a separate quoting context inside every [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).
- `$()` is a clearer way to establish a command substitution, because it can be nested much easier.

Consequently you'd typically write `myfiles=('file with spaces.csv')` and `echo "first line is $(head -1 "$file_name")"`.